# Call JQuery Function to affect multiple divs but not at once

Tags: jquery, html

The easiest thing to do is show the example and link. Bottom line - I will have TONS of these inputs and want to call a Time Picker function to each one without having to write a function for each div id.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/xva1ots0/)**

What I have to do now:

```
  $(function () {
      $('#timei1-1').datetimepicker({
          pickDate: false,
          pickSeconds: true
      });
  });

  $(function () {
      $('#timeo1-1').datetimepicker({
          pickDate: false,
          pickSeconds: true
      });
  });
```

What I hope to do...something like this to call the function on multiple divs:

```
  $(function () {
      $('#timei1-1' || '#timeo1-1').datetimepicker({
          pickDate: false,
          pickSeconds: true
      });
  });
```

That method does not currently work - it only gets the first input. I'm sure there is something easy I'm missing here. Please help :)

Comment: You can give all of them a shared `class` or change your selector slightly to something like `[id^="time"]` (id starts with). http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/xva1ots0/3/ or http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/xva1ots0/2/

Comment: This isn't specific to the datetimepicker. You'd select a group of elements here the same way you'd select any group of elements in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them all a class, and use:

```
$(".timepick").datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    pickSeconds: true
});
```

If you really want to list multiple IDs, you separate them with commas:

```
$("#timei1-1, #timeo1-1").datetimepicker({
    pickDate: false,
    pickSeconds: true
});
```

Comment: I tried the commas and it didn't work. I _thought_ I had tried a class and couldn't get it to work either, but it does now. This is one of those "duh" moments. I'm sure I screwed up something small in my tests. Thanks!

Comment: I'll bet you put the commas outside the quotes, like you did with `||`.

Comment: Programming is very simple, things are very consistent. `||` doesn't have a different meaning inside a jQuery call than it does anywhere else. No matter where you write it, it returns only one of its arguments. It doesn't magically do something different when it's in the jQuery argument list.

Comment: I did do the commas outside the quotes. Thanks for the feedback - I'm very much a copy/paste kind of "programmer". I'm doing a bunch of CSS work right now and trying to learn as much of the back end as possible. You guys are all a huge help!

Comment: Be warned, I don't have much patience for copy-paste programmers. You'll never learn unless you understand what you're doing, not just pasting blindly and then editing randomly until it works.

Comment: Well thank you for the patience you extended here. It was quite helpful. I'm getting better at this slowly but surely and it's in large part due to a strong community.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this would be to add a class to all of the input elements you want (like `dateTimePicker` or something).  All you would have to do with jQuery is:

```
$(function () {
    $('.dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
        pickDate: false,
        pickSeconds: true
    });
});
```

The selector will see all of the elements with the class `dateTimePicker`